# Discord.py Bot doesn't connect to VC

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to connect my bot to the same voice channel the author of the command is and play a video of their choice.

However, when running the following code:

```
async def join(ctx, search: str):
    vc = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=ctx.author.voice)
    voice = await vc.connect()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    if not voice.is_playing():
        await vc.connect()
        author = ctx.message.author
        query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
        html_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
        search_content = html_content.read().decode()
        search_results = re.findall(r'\/watch\?v=\w+', search_content)
        vid_url = f'https://www.youtube.com{search_results[0]}'
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(vid_url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        voice.is_playing()
```

I get this error:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'`

The error is saying that the variable 'vc' is equal to None, but I don't know why. I do have a suspicion that there is something wrong with the `vc = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=ctx.author.voice)` statement

Comment: The bot now connects to the VC flawlessly, however, it does not play any sound. Does anyone have an idea why that might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the problem is with the line

```
vc = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=ctx.author.voice)
```

Specifically, `name=ctx.author.voice` filters on the `channel.name` equaling the author's VoiceStatus, which are completely different types and will never match, so you of course get `None`.

Instead, you probably want to match on the the `ctx.author.voice.channel`, and specifically the channel `id`, rather than `name`, to avoid potential collisions.

Altogether, you want:

```
vc = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
```

I'd also throw in an if statement to check that the user/author is in fact in a voice channel, otherwise `ctx.author.voice.channel.id` itself will raise an AttributeError, since `channel` will be `None` if they're not in a VoiceChannel when they send the command.

Comment: Thanks for the help!